# Como pegar imagem de usuario na sessão e adicionar no html?

Tags: java, html, imagem, spring

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao web usando o spring boot. Ja tenho imagem salva do usuario no banco, agora gostaria de atribuir a imagem do usuario logado na sessao na foto do perfil da minha dashboard. Como fazer isso? Eu consigo trazer outras informaçoes como nome e cnpf, mas a imagem dele nao consigo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@Autowired
private UsuarioService service;
@RequestMapping("/index")
public ModelAndView index(HttpSession session) {
    Usuario usuario = service.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/home");
    session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
    return mv;
}
```

Minha pagina html:

```
<div class="avatar">

                    <img th:src="@{/session.usuario/image/{image_id}(image_id=${session.usuario.id})}">
                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h1 class="h6" th:text="${session.usuario.nome}"></h1>
                    <p class="h2" th:text="${session.usuario.cnpjCpf}"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Veja se as respostas [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400994/how-to-display-image-from-mysql-database-using-spring-mvc) lhe ajudam.

Comment: @StatelessDev nao necessariamente, isso dai eu ja faço la em detalhes, a questao é, tenho que pegar a imagem do usuario na sessao, pois se for conforme na resposta que mandou eu teria que fazer isso para todos os controladores, se nao retornaria objeto nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, nesta [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400994/how-to-display-image-from-mysql-database-using-spring-mvc) há uma resposta que pode ser útil, a segunda solução tem a linha:

> mav.addObject("userImage", base64Encoded );

Troque para:

> session.setAttribute("fotoUsuario", base64Encoded);

E no JSP use:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${fotoUsuario}" />
```

Comment: Não esqueça de utilizar o restante da solução para transformar sua imagem em Base64.